# Datepicker getData() resulting in null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new with datepickers, and in order to get a date picked by a user I'm using the function getData(), I've seen a lot of examples of people using this function and getting the date picked by the user correctly, however, when I use it and the console.log the result, it comes out as null, here's my HTML and JS for this datepicker

HTML:

```
<label for="datePickerOrders" class="labelDateOrders">Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="dateFood" class="datePickerOrders" name="datePickerOrders">
```

JS:

```
$(".datePickerOrders").change(async (event) => {

  const dateSelected = $(".datePickerOrders").datepicker("getDate");
  console.log(dateSelected);

});
```

I was expecting that the date picked was actually logged in the console, however, the output is Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to say `getDate()`. Here's a snippet that uses the `getDate()` function on a `Date` object.

```js
const datePicker = document.querySelector('.datePickerOrders');

datePicker.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let date = new Date(datePicker.value.replace(/-/g, '\/'));
  console.log(date.toDateString());
})
```

```html
<label for="datePickerOrders" class="labelDateOrders">Date:</label>
<input type="date" id="dateFood" class="datePickerOrders" name="datePickerOrders">
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly; however, if I select, for example: "10/01/2023" on the datpicker, the console logs "Mon Jan 09 2023", exactly one day before the selected one, you can try this by yourself by clicking the option "Run code snippet" on your comment and selecting a date

Comment: @DavidRamirez thanks for pointing that out, it's been updated!

Answer (score 0):

[image: jQuery Official Document]

From the official document, it returns `null` if no date has been selected.
Therefore, check if you selected a date from it.

It looks like the `getDate()` works properly as it returns `null`, because if the Datepicker couldn't find the DOM element, then it will return `undefined`